# Routing in Angularjs and express

Tags: html, css, angularjs, node.js, express

I have created a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jWsDUdp5oxn9khwISw36?p=info) with my code, which includes these routes.

```
'use strict';

 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ui.router','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$log){
     // controller code....
 })
 .config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider',function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl: '/views/home_page.html',
    resolve: {
      loggedin: checkLoggedin
    }
  })
  .state('admin', {
    url:'/admin',
    templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
    resolve: {
      loggedin: checkLoggedin
    }
  })
  .state('login', {
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
  });

}]) // end of config()
```

I am facing problem in routing. I have created **login.html** file , I am successfully logging in , after login it is redirecting to **home_page.html** , in this page I have created **nav bar** and few things. But if I click link **admin** from home page , it is showing only the admin page content , it is not showing **nav bar** in admin page. In **index.html** page I am using **ui-view**, but still it is not displaying home page's **nav bar** in other pages. 
If I go to other pages other than **home_page.html** it is not showing **nav bar.**

If I write **nav bar** code in **index.html** then on the login screen also it will display **nav bar**. On login screen it should not display **nav bar**. please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: How it relates to serverside? I mean `node.js` and `express` tags

Comment: I am using that server part for checking user name and password, basically for logging purpose... Any problem with the routing...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the **nav bar** on every page after login, you must use nested views. 
Mean, you define a "master" view where you have your nav-bar and define there a container, content (admin, main page) have to go in.

When I look at your source above, you not defined any nested view.
Good description and examples how to do this can be found [here](http://engineering.thinknear.com/blog/2015/01/07/advanced-angular-ui-router-part-i/).

*Cause the explanation would be to long for here, I provide the link.*

Comment: Thank you very much for he reply. Now the code is working properly.